# SVN st: what do these status mean?

Tags: svn

After I merged a trunk into my branch to get the latest changes, I merged my branch into trunk . Then did an snv st and this was part of the output that puzzeld me:

```
R  +    path/to/dirA
M      path/to/dirB
```

I also got the "A" status for directories I added which I understand. But it is only the status above that I do not understand especially that there was no changes made to these directories. When I did an svn diff on one of these directories I got `Property changes on: path/to/dirA`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`svn help status` is actually really good.

I'll paste the relevant pieces:

> ```
> First column: Says if item was added, deleted, or otherwise changed
>   ' ' no modifications
>   'A' Added
>   'C' Conflicted
>   'D' Deleted
>   'I' Ignored
>   'M' Modified
>   'R' Replaced
>   'X' an unversioned directory created by an externals definition
>   '?' item is not under version control
>   '!' item is missing (removed by non-svn command) or incomplete
>   '~' versioned item obstructed by some item of a different kind
>
> Second column: Modifications of a file's or directory's properties
>   ' ' no modifications
>   'C' Conflicted
>   'M' Modified
>
> Fourth column: Scheduled commit will contain addition-with-history
>   ' ' no history scheduled with commit
>   '+' history scheduled with commit
>
> Seventh column: Whether the item is the victim of a tree conflict
>   ' ' normal
>   'C' tree-Conflicted
> ```

So the first one the directory was replaced with a copy (or a move).  E.G.

```
svn rm path/to/dirA
svn cp path/to/someOtherDir path/to/dirA
```

Second one is probably a property modification given that it is a directory and a directory can't have a M in the first column since that implies a modification to the text.  It looks like there's a missing column at the start which was probably a space.

`svn diff` is not very good at showing tree changes since it outputs in unidiff by default which doesn't have provide a way of specifying tree changes.  However `svn diff --git` does a better job since the git format does provide for specifying tree changes.

Given your question after a merge I'm guessing you're wondering if those are successful merges.  The thing to look for with merges is conflicts which will either show up as a C in the first, second or seventh column.  First column is a text conflict, second column is a property conflict and seventh column would be a tree conflict.

SVN 1.8 when it comes out will also show annotations under tree modifications in status that will say where the node came from or went if it was part of a move.